# Sql Select number of rows based on specific field value

Tags: sql, row

I have two tables
1-Questions Table:
[image]

2-QuestionTypes Table:
[image]

I want to select number of rows based on question_type_id field as example [SELECT 2 question] where [question_type_id = 2] and [SELECT 5 questions] where [question_type_id = 2] and so on

Answer (score 0):

just use the LIMIT clause with the query like if you want 5 outputs use LIMIT 5 and for two questions use LIMIT 2..

exmaple for selecting five questions

```
SELECT * FROM Question_Table where question_type_id = 2 limit 5;
```

and for two questions

```
SELECT * FROM Question_Table where question_type_id = 2 limit 2;
```

and to guarantee reproducible results you can use top clause for example

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Question_Table where question_type_id = 2;

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Question_Table where question_type_id = 2;
```

and so on....

Comment: This doesn't guarantee reproducible results without sorting.

Comment: you want same output everytime you fire the query? there is a way you can use top clause. i have edited the answer do reffer

Comment: `TOP` and `LIMIT` do the same job – two alternative syntaxes, typically specific DBMS support only one of. To guarantee reproducible results you need to `ORDER BY` some appropriate column instead.

Comment: but they will give excat same output everytime without any orderby

Comment: Hm... Indeed, MySql *seems* to implicitly sort on primiary key, if nothing else is given – you cannot rely on in the general case, consider e.g. [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/1VMcWvcZ), while I did not manage to drive MySQL into the same behaviour. MySQL doesn't support `TOP`, by the way (just as PostgreSQL doesn't either).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE question_type_id = 2 LIMIT 2;


SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE question_type_id = 2 LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee reproducible results without sorting.

Comment: That's true. But the requirements of OP are unclear in this regard. If only "X arbitrary questions of type Y" are required, this would be sufficient.